# Unregister class handler from control - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have registered the event handler for `GotFocusEvent` over the textbox in WPF.

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_GotFocus));
```

Now,Is there a way to remove the registered handler from textbox?

**UPDATE:**
I checked the following link

[WPF Custom Routed Events - How to UnSubscribe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866458/wpf-custom-routed-events-how-to-unsubscribe)

However, it didn't helped me since the mentioned control is custom control where as it is default `TextBox` control in my case.

I'm not able to find `RemoveHandler` in my case.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The RemoveHandler Method is probably the right way to approach this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.removehandler.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Custom Routed Events - How to UnSubscribe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866458/wpf-custom-routed-events-how-to-unsubscribe)

Comment: @Nicholas, I didn't find `RemoveHandler` for `TextBox`.  Any suggestion?

Comment: You cannot unregister a `ClassHandler`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you use `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler`? Why don't you use `UIElement.RegisterHandler` instead? As @Novitchi stated correctly, you cannot unregister class handlers.

Comment: @feO2x,  Yes,  I need to open the OSK if the app doesn't connected with keyboard.  I will register the class handler to `TestBox` so that it will open OSK.exe whenever Control get focus and will close the same in focus lost.  I can able to find that user has connected the keyboard to the system, In this case, I need to unregister the class handler to stop triggering keyboard on focus.  Hope I am clear.

Comment: I know I can have `bool` to find,  but I'm looking for optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments of your question, Class Handlers cannot be unregistered. My suggestion to you would be the following: add an if statement at the beginning of your handler where you check if the actual method body should execute or not. This could look like the following:

```cs
private void MyTextBoxClassHandler (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckIfHandlerShouldExecute() == false)
        return;

    // The actual code that should be executed in the handler resides here.
}
```

This does not prevent that the handler is being called but your logic is not executed if a certain condition is not met.

Comment: I have already mentioned this in my comments of my question.  It could be a workaround but not the answer.

Comment: Well, the answer is that there is no API to unregister class handlers as mentioned in the comments. The only way to circumvent this problem is to not use class handlers, but some other mechanism, e.g. an attached property that you set on all text boxes via a style. This attached property registers and deregisters itself to the text box when a certain value is provided (you can learn more here: http://briannoyes.net/2012/12/20/attached-behaviors-vs-attached-properties-vs-blend-behaviors/).

Comment: do yourself an humanity a favor (no offense) and write `if (!ShouldHandlerExecute()) return;`

Comment: @EricG I usually don't like the `!` operator because I think it can be easily missed when reading source code - a `== false` is hard to miss.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to unregister the class handler, but you could manage the events in a static class where you register the class handler once and add / remove your instance handlers as needed. You could expose normal `EventHandlers` or one could use reactive extensions to achieve that:

```
public static class GlobalEvents
{
    static readonly ClassHandlerSubject s_TextBoxGotFocus = new ClassHandlerSubject(typeof(TextBox), UIElement.GotFocusEvent);
    public static IObservable<RoutedEventArgs> TextBoxGotFocus => s_TextBoxGotFocus.Events;

    class ClassHandlerSubject
    {
        readonly Lazy<Subject<RoutedEventArgs>> m_Subject;
        public IObservable<RoutedEventArgs> Events => m_Subject.Value;

        public ClassHandlerSubject(Type classType, RoutedEvent routedEvent) =>
            m_Subject = new Lazy<Subject<RoutedEventArgs>>(() =>
            {
                EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(classType, routedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnEventReceived));
                return new Subject<RoutedEventArgs>();
            });

        private void OnEventReceived(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => m_Subject.Value.OnNext(e);
    }
}
```

Use it like that:

```
//subscribe
var subscription = GlobalEvents.TextBoxGotFocus.Subscribe(TextBox_GotFocus);
//... receive events
//remove my subscription
subscription.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one instance of the class you want to subscribe to the event at a time.
Similarly to @Alex's, I instead call a static event within the class. And in the constructor I grab an instance reference to then use for my event.

```
public partical class MyWindow : Window
{
    public static MyWindow Current { get; private set; }

    public MyWindow() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
    }

    static MyWindow()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(MyWindow),
                System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.KeyUpEvent,
                new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(AllKeyUp_static), true);
    }

    private static void AllKeyUp_static(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Current?.AllKeyUp_instance(sender, e);
    }

    private void AllKeyUp_instance(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         // HANDLE EVENT
    }
}
```

This will do two things. First, it keeps your prior class instances from becoming un-collectable for garbage disposal. And two - automatically assign the current instance to make use of the event.